# LGBMClassifier has no attribute apply - Probability Calibration

Tags: python, lightgbm

I am trying to calibrate the LGBM probabilities by using the end-nodes(leaves).

I am following this link :

[Probability Calibration](http://gdmarmerola.github.io/probability-calibration/)

However, I am unable to add the apply function on the fit LGBM model.

I keep getting the error :

'LGBMClassifier' object has no attribute 'apply'

I tried to look through the documentation and it seems like I am missing something.

Can someone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess, linked blog post might be based on initial versions of Lightgbm.

In current version (3.1.0), we can get leaf index using `predict` method.

`lgb.predict(..., pred_leaf = True)` , default value is False.

Works with both sklearn wrapper classes (`LGBMClassifier`) & `import lightgbm as lgb`.

Attaching Lightgbm documentation links for reference

- [Lightgbm Booster - predict method](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.predict)
- [Sklearn Wrapper - predict method](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict)

Comment: Hey, yeah. This worked after the update. Thanks.